# fields with decimals - which data type to use?

Tags: mysql

I need a field with percentages

```
25% => 0.25
30% => 0.30
```

Which data type do I need to set the field to?

And how can you determine the range of fields with decimals like integer fields? (eg. tinyint unsigned is 0-255)

### Edit

I need to do some calculation in my queries

Answer (score 2):

use [**DECIMAL DATATYPE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html)

```
DECIMAL[(M[,D])] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
```

> For MySQL 5.0.3 and above:
>
> A packed “exact” fixed-point number. M
>   is the total number of digits (the
>   precision) and D is the number of
>   digits after the decimal point (the
>   scale). The decimal point and (for
>   negative numbers) the “-” sign are not
>   counted in M. If D is 0, values have
>   no decimal point or fractional part.
>   The maximum number of digits (M) for
>   DECIMAL is 65 (64 from 5.0.3 to
>   5.0.5). The maximum number of supported decimals (D) is 30. If D is
>   omitted, the default is 0. If M is
>   omitted, the default is 10.
>
> UNSIGNED, if specified, disallows
>   negative values.
>
> All basic calculations (+, -, *, /)
>   with DECIMAL columns are done with a
>   precision of 65 digits.

note: if you want that that field maximum value between 0-99.99 then use

```
ALTER TABLE  `table_name` ADD  `percentage` DECIMAL( 5, 2 ) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Of the [plethora of MySQL numeric types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html), the [FLOAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html#id36419238) or [REAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html#id36419238) may be your best bet (depends on what you're storing).

Answer (score 0):

you should use FLOAT field with at leas 5 bits

Comment: FLOAT can introduce rounding errors. MySQL has a fixed decimal type

Answer (score 0):

How about `decimal`? :)

You can even set the precision:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable ( percentage decimal(10,2) ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want a `DECIMAL` type; `FLOAT` suffers from the same imprecision that all floats do.